# How to hide the Start button in Windows 10

Tags: windows, taskbar, windows-10

In Windows 8, Microsoft removed the Start button. I've upgraded to Windows 10 and the Start button has made an appearance again.

I've checked the **taskbar context menu** and it allows me to remove:

- Search bar/icon
- Task View button
- Touch keyboard button

In System Settings > Notifications & Actions > **Turn system icons on or off**, I see:

- Clock
- Volume
- Network
- Power
- Input indicator
- Location
- Action Center

None of which I want to remove. I find it a bit ridiculous that you can remove the clock as well as all the other icons but not the Start button.

I'd prefer not installing a third-party app for this purpose if possible, however I am open to the idea of it. Covering up that square of my screen is not an acceptable solution as it does not allow me to gain that square of screen real estate on my taskbar.

**Is there a way to remove the Start button?**

Comment: Hiding start button i think it is not possible.

Comment: This is t a feature of Windows 10 this requires third-party software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, the Start button is a core feature of the operating system and is unable to be disabled as if it was a toggleable part of the taskbar. Although you should be able to auto-hide the taskbar so it fades out view when not being used, and will only come back when you hover your cursor over the bottom of the screen.